# Hidden stars are not shown but still get printed in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In emacs org-mode, I hide leading-stars using org-hide-leading-stars.
This works well on the screen, however, when I printed with ps-print-buffer-with-faces, the leading stars reappear in a black color in the paper.

As I understand, org-hide-leading-stars make the color of stars the same as background, and hence making them look disappeared. 
Since my background is white, the stars became white. Hence, they are not supposed to be printed in the paper, right?

Please help.

Comment: Not an answer, but in general, I'd suggest exporting your Org buffer to something better suited for printing, such as ASCII. Or better yet to HTML or PDF.

Comment: You could also create a temporary buffer and programmatically delete the leading starts with the proper regexp replace all . . . ., and then use your ps-print . . . .

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use the low level ps-print-buffer-with-faces function to print your buffer rather than using one of the built-in export options of org-mode? You could try manually setting the org-hide face and see if that works.

Comment: Juancho - I used HTML export before, but I like more in the way that it is displayed in emacs.

Comment: lawlist - If I delete the reading stars, the colors of tag and text changes, since the levels are not properly recognized.

Comment: Tim X - I tried org-hide face, but it doesn't work as I expected. I think it is to do with background color. I will update the post with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding stars is done by an emacs overlay which only affects the display: the underlying buffer/file still contains the asterisks, so ps-print-buffer will print them out. As the comments suggest, you either have to export to some format and print that out, or modify the buffer temporarily to print it out.